# PostgreSQL deadlock updating only one row

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, database-deadlocks, amazon-aurora

Today our production database (Aurora PostgreSQL 9.6.3) encountered a deadlock condition wherein multiple processes were attempting to perform the same `UPDATE` query on a single row. We thought deadlock could only occur when updating multiple rows out of order, so this was a surprise; however, it did happen at the busiest time of the day for us.

Here's the transaction in our Python code that contains the `UPDATE` statement (it's a poor man's `UPSERT`):

```
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE students SET name = %s WHERE uuid = %s AND activity_id = %s""", (name, uuid, activityId))

    if cursor.rowcount <= 0:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO students (name, uuid, activity_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (name, uuid, activityId))

    if cursor.rowcount <= 0:
        self.connection.rollback()
        raise BaseDao.NotUpserted("No student name was updated or inserted for activity_id %d and uuid %s" % (activityId, uuid))
    else:
        self.connection.commit()
```

Here are some relevant lines from the log, including the simple query that updates just one row:

```
...
2018-01-19 16:21:27 UTC:[38161]:ERROR:  deadlock detected
2018-01-19 16:21:27 UTC:[38161]:DETAIL:  Process 38161 waits for ShareLock on transaction 90490253; blocked by process 25147.
    Process 25147 waits for ShareLock on transaction 90490267; blocked by process 38161.
    Process 38161: UPDATE students SET name = 'foobar' WHERE uuid = 'ca1b2d153cbdc9574cce' AND activity_id = 35473237
    Process 25147: UPDATE students SET name = 'foobar' WHERE uuid = 'ca1b2d153cbdc9574cce' AND activity_id = 35473237
...
```

And here are the two relevant tables:

```
db=> \d students
                                        Table "public.students"
    Column   |          Type          |                             Modifiers                             
-------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('students_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying(128) | not null
 uuid        | character varying(40)  | not null
 activity_id | integer                | not null
Indexes:
    "students_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "students_activity_id" btree (activity_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "activity_id_refs_id_76c08098" FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activities(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

db=> \d activities
                                       Table "public.activities"
      Column       |           Type           |                              Modifiers                               
-------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                  | not null default nextval('activities_id_seq'::regclass)
 start_time        | timestamp with time zone | not null
 end_time          | timestamp with time zone | 
 activity_type     | character varying(2)     | not null
 activity_id       | integer                  | not null
 started_by_id     | integer                  | not null
 activity_state    | integer                  | not null
 legacy_id         | integer                  | 
 hide_report       | boolean                  | not null
 report_status     | integer                  | 
 students_finished | text                     | not null
 room_name         | text                     | 
 last_updated      | timestamp with time zone | 
 state             | integer                  | 
Indexes:
    "activities_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "activities_end_time" btree (end_time)
    "activities_room_name_c1f9997a_like" btree (room_name text_pattern_ops)
    "activities_room_name_c1f9997a_uniq" btree (room_name)
    "activities_started_by_id" btree (started_by_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "started_by_id_refs_id_5ea35c7a" FOREIGN KEY (started_by_id) REFERENCES users(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "students" CONSTRAINT "activity_id_refs_id_76c08098" FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activities(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

How can we get into a deadlock like this when only one row is being updated?

Comment: You can't deadlock with just one contended resource. Do you have triggers on `students`? Rewrite rules? What are the two transaction executing besides that update? Can you reproduce by executing the updates manually from two `psql` instances?

Comment: We don't have any triggers or rewrite rules on `students`. Unfortunately I don't know what two transactions were executing besides that update, and I can't reproduce manually from `psql`. However, we have since discovered that we were inadvertently allowing students to fire off multiple HTTP requests to set their name (by typing a name and holding down the "Enter" key). We think this may be what happened, but we're not sure how to prove it.

Comment: If it's concurrence-related than it is nondeterministic; to increase the chance of the bug happening, you could try to artificially increase the latency in your test environment (ie: add some sleep() in strategic places) and fire up a few concurrent requests... personally, I would rather enable/add logging of all the sql activity, run one HTTP request to get the list of sql statements and then analyse them for resource access/reproduce via psql

Comment: Good luck with this heisenbug! :-)

Comment: Your code snippet does not show the transaction *start*. There may be more commands taking locks. And `REFERENCES activities(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` might play a role in this, since it defers the FK check to the end of the transaction. Why are your FK constraints `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` to begin with? (And why not use a proper `UPSERT`?)

Comment: The start of the transaction is handled automatically by the psycopg2 module we use, which defaults to opening a transaction before executing the first statement (this is why our code has calls to `rollback()` or `commit()` at the end). I'll have to do some research to get answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons for such a deadlock:

1. The transaction that performs the updates contains more than one statement, and the other statements created locks too.
2. There are triggers involved that create additional locks.

Remember that deadlocks are not bugs unless they occur too often; failure to handle deadlocks is a bug. Just retry the failed transaction.

Comment: Indeed there are two statements in the transaction, but the other is an `INSERT` so we didn't think it was contributing to the problem. I've updated my post with the two statements.

Comment: One thing you could do to get closer to a solution is to query `pg_locks` right before the end of the transaction to figure out what is actually locked. And remember: it is not a bug.